# how do I add color to output in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip

I want to have colored error messages in VScode.

I tried to install the [Output Colorizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer) extension but it didn't work.

I also tried to change the `sitecustomize.py` file by using the `coloredlogs` and `IPython` libraries but it didn't work either way:

when I tried to use coloredlogs I got this error message:

```
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coloredlogs'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sitecustomize.py", line 1, in <module>
    import coloredlogs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coloredlogs'
```

even though I tried the demo and it worked.

Comment: -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the extension "Output Colorizer", it is for changing the color of the log file in "OUTPUT": "*Syntax highlighting for log files*":

   [image]
2. For using the module "`coloredlogs`", we need to install this module in the currently selected python environment (lower left corner of VS Code).

   (install: `pip install coloredlogs`  check: `pip show coloredlogs`)

   [image]

Reference: [Python environment in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).